# How to add to types initially loaded in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How do I add to the list of .NET assemblies that are loaded at start up in PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on PowerShell 2.0 use the Add-Type cmdlet to add the assemblies e.g.:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

You can use the AssemblyName parameter to add one of the standard .NET assemblies.  If you have your own custom assemblies that you want to always load use the -Path parameter e.g.:

```
Add-Type -Path "$home\foo.dll"
```

Invoke the Add-Type cmdlet from your profile to make sure the .NET types contained in the added assemblies are always available in your PowerShell sessions.  For more info on profiles execute:

```
Get-Help about_profiles
```